# i wants to import csv in codeigniter framework.but showing the error like Undefined property: Cforcecontroller::$csvimport

Tags: php, codeigniter

i wants to import csv in PHP codeigniter.am getting error.
this is my controller

```
 function importcsv() {
    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/csv/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->load->view('cforce/enquiryform');
    } else {

        $file_data = $this->upload->data();

        $file_path =  './uploads/csv/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            var_dump($csv_array);die;
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                $insert_data = array(
                    'name'=>$row['name'],
                    'subject'=>$row['subject'],
                    'mark'=>$row['mark'],

                );
                $this->Adminpanelmodel->insert_csv($insert_data);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url().'csv');
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);
        } else 
            $data['error'] = "Error occured";
            $this->load->view('cforce/enquiryform');
        }

    }
```

Comment: seems you forgot to load library. add line `$this->load->library('csvimport');` , it will work.

Comment: i added library now.but getting error

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 1264

Backtrace:

File: /home/codestime/public_html/ct102/application/controllers/Cforcecontroller.php
Line: 7701
Function: library

File: /home/codestime/public_html/ct102/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Answer (score 0):

either you forget to load csvimport library, or you should check in your controller "cforce" that is there any file named "enquiryform". Means you should inspect this line - $this->load->view('cforce/enquiryform'); 
If this not work, make your controller's first letter in uppercase.May be it'll work for you.

Comment: classnames in php are case insensitive

Comment: In codeignitor, it should be in uppercase, it can run in lowercase on localhost, but not on live server.

Comment: i changed it as uppercase..but show some error like this

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 1264

Backtrace:

File: /home/codestime/public_html/ct102/application/controllers/Cforcecontroller.php
Line: 7701
Function: library

File: /home/codestime/public_html/ct102/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: what's there on line `Cforcecontroller.php Line: 7701`?